# Is "such as occurred in" in a parenthetical sentence correct?

Tags: grammaticality

In the following sentence, is the *such as occurred in Katrina* part  grammatically correct?

> Eyewall replacement cycles, **such as occurred in Katrina** as it approached the Gulf Coast of the United States, can greatly increase the size of tropical cyclones.

[Context](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Eyewall_replacement_cycle#Identification)

---

An alternative,

> Eyewall replacement cycles, such as **those that** occurred in Katrina as it approached the Gulf Coast of the United States, can greatly increase the size of tropical cyclones.

seems to be clumsy.

Comment: Using "those that" is correct.  You might instead say, "...replacement cycles, as they occurred in Katrina..."

Comment: I have no problem with either. Essentially, "those that" is implicit in the first.

Comment: *That* is gradually being dropped -- dropping *those that* without causing ambiguity or incompleteness is catching on. The sentence is fine per current usage. Could risk being considered incorrect by some old timers, though.

Comment: @Kris  I'm about as old-time and crotchety as they come and I have no problem with it. But I'd prefer "like those which occurred . . ." to either.

Comment: @StoneyB We may have second thoughts after TimLymington raised a new point (see below).

Comment: @Kris  I never imagined I was adopting a popular position. I just prefer "such" before the noun, "like" after it.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I would consider such use to be colloquial at best and I'm unsurprised to see that the OP is quoting from a [Wikipedia page](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Eyewall_replacement_cycle#Identification). However, [thanks to Ngrams](http://books.google.com/ngrams/graph?content=such%20as%20occurred,such%20as%20those%20that%20occurred&year_start=1770&year_end=2008&corpus=0&smoothing=3), I've just had the proverbial rugs (*I try to double-rug myself when on ELU*) pulled from under my feet:

[image: such as occurred in]

The blue worm represents "*such as occurred*" which has apparently seen consistent use right from ~1800. The red, signifying "*such as those that occurred*", is practically flat-lined until the 1960s. Other alternatives including "*such as the one that occurred*", "*such as the ones that occurred*", etc. barely register in the plot. "*Like those that occurred*" and its variants fare better, albeit on a similar scale.

A few relevant excerpts from (Google) books which employ the phrase *such as occurred in*:

**2012**: *The Oxford Handbook of Latin American Political Economy*

> A third path is when political elites split, and agree to democratize in order to avoid violence (Bardhan 1993), *such as occurred in Colombia*. A final path is that democratic institutions develop and thrive when public goods become more highly ...

**1941**: *Grain prices and the futures market: a 15-year survey, 1923-1938*

> The records disclose instead either concurrent price and large-scale position changes, *such as occurred in March and April 1925*, or an absence of any definite relationship. Added insight into the character of large-scale trading can be ...

**1885**: *Medical and Surgical Reporter*

> The cases I am about to report, are *such as occurred in my practice during the past four years*. From 1875 to 1881, we had eight different times, attempted the removal of pieces of gun cap, iron or steel, from the vitreous by aid of forceps.

**1855**: *The American journal of the medical sciences: Volume 29*

> Some pigment was also found external to the vessels, and perhaps was the residuum of punctiform hemorrhages, but no fresh punctiform hemorrhages, *such as occurred in the brain*, were ever seen in the kidneys. The pigment was found, ...

**1819**: *Voyage to South America*

> In being released from the shackles of their old system, and without any settled re-organization of government, it was natural to be expected, that during the sway of the passions, scenes *such as occurred in France*, would take place.

Google Books returns *863,000* results for ["*such as occurred*"](http://www.google.com/search?q=%22such%20as%20occurred%22&btnG=Search%20Books&tbm=bks) versus *24,300* for ["*such as those that occurred*"](http://www.google.com/search?q=%22such%20as%20those%20that%20occurred%22&btnG=Search%20Books&tbm=bks).

These surprises should mean that I ought to stand corrected. I am, however, unable to bring myself to do it. So, somebody please find something wrong with this entire exercise. I, for one, will be extremely receptive.

Comment: BTW, the comparative graphs for [those which occurred](http://i.stack.imgur.com/kOqMP.png) are interesting.

Comment: @tchrist I wonder if all these variants add up to something significant ...

Answer (score 1):

I don't think your alternatives are precisely equivalent.  *Such as occurred...*, just like *cycles as occurred in Katrina...*, seems to me to be describing a subset of eyewall cycles, and as such should strictly dispense with the parenthetical commas. *Such as those that occurred...*, or (better) *like those that occurred...* is a simple, parenthetical example.

Of course, even if I'm right, the distinction is too fine to  matter in 99% of cases; but is that a reason to blur it entirely? Not on this site, at least.

Comment: Must say, one of those that never occurred to me until I read this. Well, can't help but agree. Where that subtle distinction does exist, it must be projected correctly.